# How to use YEAR function SQL when typing custom queries using Spring JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c from Comment as c WHERE YEAR(c.news.event.fromDate) = :year ORDER BY c.created DESC")
List<Comment> getNewsCommentOrderByCreatedDesc(@Param("year") int year);
```

Trying to write this as custom query:

```
String queryString = "from Comment as comment where YEAR(news.event.fromDate) = :year order by created desc";
```

This is not working because JPA dont support YEAR() function, if I am not wrong? How can i write `queryString` the right way as custom query ?

Thank you!

Comment: did you get an error? JPA have YEAR https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date and your query seems correct

Comment: IntelliJ gives me this error `<expression>, <operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got '('` between YEAR and `(` , https://share.getcloudapp.com/7KumAGpb

Comment: So the problem is not with `YEAR`!

Comment: Cant i have `c.news.event.fromDate` inside parenthesis ?